# What is the default multiplication technique used for notation "wv"

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have two vectors, $w$ and $v$. Then my professor writes on the board $wv$. Does this refer to the dot product or cross product?

Comment: Why don't you ask your professor?

Comment: Usually dot. $\phantom{}$

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I did. I was just wondering if there was a convention.